# 'expires_in' missing from Facebook oauth/access_token response

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I've just noticed that this method is failing in my ASP.NET web application because I'm not catering for 'expires_in' being missing in the response.

I haven't changed any code recently, and was not aware of any reason for this to be missing in the response. Does this mean that the token has expired?

I'm using version 7.0.6 of the C# Facebook SDK and v2.5 of the Facebook Graph API.

The JSON response looks like this:

```
{"access_token":"xxxx","token_type":"bearer"}
```

Comment: I've noticed the same thing today, and am using the API directly rather than through an SDK. I'm using the latest version of the API, v2.10.

Comment: I have same issue. I am using facebook sdk in python...

Comment: I've mentioned this on the Facebook developers group, and linked back to this post. Might be good to click "like" on it or comment to get some visibility. https://www.facebook.com/groups/fbdevelopers/permalink/1543552945688214/

Comment: I can confirm that this issue happens with v2.6 and with unversioned requests.

Comment: _“Might be good to click "like" on it or comment to get some visibility”_ - subscribing to the bug report is a better idea - https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1829057490667058/ Bugs get prioritized based on how many devs/apps are affected.

Comment: I agree. Wasn't aware of their bug tracker. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There is an [open bug report about this on Facebook's bug tracker](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1829057490667058/). Given Facebook's response it does indeed sound like it's a bug on their end, and appeared some time yesterday.

Updates will appear in that bug report, and you can subscribe to it to give it more visibility and to receive updates.

<sub>Thanks to CBroe for pointing out the bug report in his comment on the question.</sub>

Comment: this bug may be fixed. check here https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1829057490667058/